# How to push a JavaScript project on Github?

Tags: javascript, git, github

I'm learning about JavaScript, Git and Github... and I'm doing a simple game in JavaScript and I just made the first push on Github. Now I see that it looks like a CSS project, not like a JavaScript project. What should I do to make this project looks like a JavaScript project on my Github. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: go inside the project and check the files

Comment: These tags are automatically generated based on line counts of different file types in your repo. It looks like at the moment, most of the code in your repo is css.

Comment: You can use `git status` to see if you have any untracked files, and `git diff origin/master`, if those are the names of the remotes and branches you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files and directories within a repository determine the languages that make up the repository. You can view a repository's languages to get a quick overview of the repository.

GitHub uses the open source [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) to determine file languages for syntax highlighting and repository statistics. Language statistics will update after you push changes to your default branch (which is usually `master`).

This is your project:

[image]

In your case, there are 1 CSS file and 1 JS file, so you can open an issue [here](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/new) regarding the misidentification your repo.

If you want to change the repo languages you can read the [How to Change Repo Language in GitHub](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-change-repo-language-in-github-c3e07819c5bb) article.